# Can I use google cloud speech api in microsoft azure vm?

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, asterisk, google-cloud-speech

I am trying to use google cloud speech API in microsoft azure machine(Where I have installed asterisk service). Is it possible to do this. Because in GCP we have an option where we can enable 'Allow all cloud API services'. But in microsoft we do not have an option to enable. If I use I am getting the following error. Please go through the staktrace and help me.

Note : we have a working version in GCP machine. Now I am deploying it into microsoft vm(Then only I am getting this error).

[image]

Comment: Do not use pictures. Edit your question and put the text into your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An API can be called over the internet. If the machine is configured to be able to connect to the internet than **yes, you can**.

Looking at the error you're getting, it looks like there's something wrong with your authentication setup.

> DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application.
>   For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started

If you follow the instructions in the linked documentation on [Getting Started with Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started), you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you @rickvdbosch . I have gone through the documentation and everything is working great now.

Answer (score 0):

Seams like i answered same less than week ago.

Please check that you setuped credentials for asterisk user, not for root. Asterisk is running under asterisk user.